# openssl_decrypt always returns false

Tags: php, encryption, encryption-symmetric, php-openssl, aes-gcm

I tried to migrate my encryption from mcrypt to openssl but the decryption keeps failing. The code Below shows my encryption function. I placed the var_dump in the encryption function to verify decryption with identical variables works, which it does not.

I tried the following changes to the code, none worked:

- `base64_decode($encrypted)`
- just out of curiosity `base64_encode($encrypted)`
- all these variants with options set to:0(default value),OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING

```
function encryptString($data){  
    $key = "1A534";

    do{
        $iv = random_bytes(100);
    }while(strpos($iv,"|Z|")!==false);

    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data,"aes-256-gcm",$key,false,$iv);   
    var_dump(openssl_decrypt($encrypted,"aes-256-gcm",$key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv));
    $output = $iv . "|Z|" . $encrypted;
    $output = base64_encode($output);   
    return $output;
}
```

PHP Version is 7.0.5-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

OpenSSL Version is OpenSSL 1.0.2g 1 Mar 2016

Why keeps openssl_decrypt returning false? I successfully encrypted with the same variables just the line above.

Comment: I think this won't work until PHP 7.1, because there is a bug with the authentication tag.

Comment: Seems right. None GCM ciphers work correctly.

Comment: I'm using 7.1 in this scenario but still getting a false returned in all scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work for PHP < 7.1 as AEAD is not supported.

You can use [the library I created](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/php-aes-gcm) (PHP 5.4+ and 7.0+).

Depending on your environment, it will test and use the following methods:

- OpenSSL on PHP 7.1,
- [libCrypto extension](https://github.com/bukka/php-crypto),
- A pure PHP implementation.

Note that the pure PHP method is very slow compared to the other methods.